# Edit protected member in php

Tags: php, protected

I have code similar to the following:

```
class ModuleRaceRegistration extends Module
{
    protected $strTemplate = "template";
    protected function compile()
    {
         // this doesn't work
         $this->strTemplate = "template2";
    }
}
```

From within the `compile` function I need to change the `$strTemplate` member. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would that not work? I can't think of a scenario when it doesn't.

Comment: I have no idea. I can `echo $this->strTemplate;` and it echos "template2" but the template2 module never gets loaded (this is a module within Contao CMS).

Comment: Figured it out. It turns out to be a race condition withing Contao CMS. You can vote to close.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is an error being returned? Also, this might not be the case but `compile` is a `protected` method so you can only call it from within the class. If you are trying to call it from outside of the class, then it would need to be `public`.

Comment: no errors.  I can echo $this->strTemplate; and it echos "template2" but the template2 module never gets loaded (this is a module within Contao CMS). `compile` does get called and `template`is loaded.

Comment: Could it be getting set back to 'template' elsewhere, later on? Out of interest how have you checked that compile is being called?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try

Example from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

```
<?php
abstract class Base {
    abstract protected function _test();
}

class Bar extends Base {

    protected function _test() { }

    public function TestFoo() {
        $c = new Foo();
        $c->_test();
    }
}

class Foo extends Base {
    protected function _test() {
        echo 'Foo';
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->TestFoo(); // result: Foo
?>
```